# DNS redundancy with DNSimple and CloudFlare

Tags: dns, cloudflare, dnsimple

I have my domain name on DNSimple, my application on Heroku and my name servers on both DNSimple and CloudFlare.

I set up DNSimple so that the first two name servers point to CloudFlare, and the second two point to DNSimple, but often I find that the name servers in DNSimple's UI are reset to all 4 DNSimple name servers.

Also, when I use whatsmydns to track my domain, I see something strange - some servers have the split DNS configuration, some servers have only DNSimple and others have only CloudFlare. It's been like this for several weeks, so it's not a propogation issue.

Any suggestions on how to set this up differently, so that all DNS servers show 2 CloudFlare DNS servers and 2 DNSimple DNS servers?

The main goal for this is to be redundant, incase of a DNS failure, like the one DNSimple suffered a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Rendundancy should not be achieved manually splitting the name servers. This approach has a lot of drawbacks.

Just to name a few, DNSimple exposes some custom records. If you use one of those custom records, they will not work on the other provider.

Moreover, you will need to manually keep in sync both providers, which may very likely result in some hard-to-debug issues in case you forget to sync a record, or in the sync you type the wrong value.

Last but not least, in theory, each provider should also be capable to advertise the name servers of the other provider.

If you truly want to be redundant, you should use a real secondary DNS system. We (DNSimple) will roll this feature out in the next weeks.

Comment: Thanks Simone - been working with someone on your team about this issue over the last couple of days, and we got it taken care of!